# Dio unit test error, type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Interceptors'

Tags: dart, unit-testing, mockito, dio

Currently I am working on my flutter app using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package as my networking and I want to create test on the dio post (wrapped within appclient). Here my code for
app_client.dart

```
abstract class AppClient{
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> get(String path, {Map<String, String>? queryParameters, Map<String, String>? headers});
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> post(String path, dynamic data, {Map<String, String>? queryParameters, Map<String, String>? headers});
}

class AppClientImpl implements AppClient{

  late Dio dio;
  late Interceptors interceptors;

  AppClientImpl({required this.dio}){
    //get language code
    String languageCode = StorageUtil.getSavedLanguage();
    if(languageCode == "id-ID"){
      languageCode = "id_ID";
    }else{
      languageCode = "en_US";
    }

    BaseOptions baseOptions = BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: ServiceUrl.baseUrl,
        headers: {
          "Accept" : "application/json",
          "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        },
        queryParameters: {
          "language" : languageCode,
          "channel" : "mobile"
        }
    );

    dio.options = baseOptions;

    interceptors = Interceptors();
    interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(request: true, requestBody: true, requestHeader: true, responseBody: true, responseHeader: true));

    //COMMENT BECAUSE FAILED WHEN TESTING
    dio.interceptors.addAll(interceptors); // ERROR HERE!!!!
  }

  @override
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> get(String path, {Map<String, String>? queryParameters, Map<String, String>? headers}) async {
    // return await dio.get(path, queryParameters: queryParameters);
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> post(String path, dynamic data, {Map<String, String>? queryParameters, Map<String, String>? headers}) async{
    Response response = await dio.post(path, queryParameters: queryParameters, data: Map<String, dynamic>.from(data));

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      return jsonDecode(response.data);
    }else{
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

}
```

and here is my test class

```
class MockDio extends Mock implements Dio{}

void main(){

  late MockDio mockDio;
  late AppClientImpl appClient;

  setUp((){
    mockDio = MockDio();
    appClient = AppClientImpl(dio: mockDio);
  });

  final tResponse = jsonDecode(fixture("token/token_success.json"));
  final tData = {};
  
  group("post method", (){
    test(
        "should return data when status code is 200",
        ()async{
          when(
              () => mockDio.post(any(), queryParameters: any(named: "queryParameters"), data: any(named: "data"))
          ).thenAnswer(
              (invocation) async => Response(requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: "/sample"), data: fixture("token/token_success.json"), statusCode: 200)
          );

          final result = await appClient.post("/sample", tData);
          verify(() => mockDio.post(any(), queryParameters: any(named: "queryParameters"), data: any(named: "data"))).called(1);

          expect(result, tResponse);

        }
    );
  });

}
```

As you can see, I inject dio instance to my appclient class and add global configuration there including interceptors.

I think everything is ok until I get these error.

```
Testing started at 08.54 ...

package:dio/src/dio.dart 46:20                                    MockDio.interceptors
package:eazyconnect/data/network/app_client/app_client.dart 44:9  new AppClientImpl
test/data/network/app_client/app_client_test.dart 23:17           main.<fn>

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Interceptors'
```

Why this is happen? Any help and suggestion would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need mock interceptors too. You need pass interceptors like parameters, for class http, you can see the list interceptors have setted on Dio instance dont no in DioMock, that's why the error are happening

Comment: Could you give me the example? I think it would be great if you provide some example.

Comment: It would be great to have an example here.